# How can I destructing array and group them as objects in another array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a result set from DB like below:

```
"result": [
    {
        "customerId": "20572696",
        "totalIncome": "260000",
        "total_Expense": "130000",
        "relationName": "VIJAYA",                                                                               
        "relationDOB": "23839",
        "relation": "Daughter"
       
    },
    {
        "customerId": "20572696",
        "totalIncome": "260000",
        "total_Expense": "130000",
        "relationName": "Riyaz",                                                               
        "relationDOB": "26665",
        "relation": "SPOUSE"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "20570000",
        "totalIncome": "200000",
        "total_Expense": "100000",
        "relationName": "John",                                                               
        "relationDOB": "26000",
        "relation": "SON"
    }
]
```

I need to format the result set like below by grouping the `customerId`, `totalIncome`, `total_Expense` and placing rest of the objects in array named `relation`.

```
"result": [{
      "customerId": "20572696",
      "totalIncome": "260000",
      "total_Expense": "130000",
      "relations": [
            {
              "relationName": "VIJAYA"                                                               
              "relationDOB": "23839 ",
              "relation": "Daughter "
            },
            {
              "relationName": "Riyaz", 
              "relationDOB": "26665",
              "relation": "SPOUSE"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
    "customerId": "20570000",
     "totalIncome": "200000",
     "total_Expense": "100000",
     "relations": [
            {
              "relationName": "John"                                                               
              "relationDOB": "26000",
              "relation": "SON"
            }]
    }
]
```

One way I think of is filtering all distinct customerId in a separate array and looping through result array and separate first three fields and placing remaining fields in a object and push it in a sub array.
But is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You forgot to add the JS code you're having issues with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this with `reduce` and `Object.values`

basically with reduce you create an object with customerId as key

then with Object.values you get rid of the customerId indices and you got your result as an array

be aware that since `20570000` in smaller than `20572696` when you return the array the order are inverted

```js
const group = data => Object.values(data.reduce((res, {customerId, totalIncome, total_Expense, ...rest}) => {

 const existing = res[customerId] || {customerId, totalIncome, total_Expense, relations:[]}
 
 return {
   ...res,
   [customerId]: {
     ...existing,
     relations: [...existing.relations, rest]
   }
 }


}, {}))



const data =  [
    {
        "customerId": "20572696",
        "totalIncome": "260000",
        "total_Expense": "130000",
        "relationName": "VIJAYA",                                                                               
        "relationDOB": "23839",
        "relation": "Daughter"
       
    },
    {
        "customerId": "20572696",
        "totalIncome": "260000",
        "total_Expense": "130000",
        "relationName": "Riyaz",                                                               
        "relationDOB": "26665",
        "relation": "SPOUSE"
    },
    {
        "customerId": "20570000",
        "totalIncome": "200000",
        "total_Expense": "100000",
        "relationName": "John",                                                               
        "relationDOB": "26000",
        "relation": "SON"
    }
]

console.log(group(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `customerId`, `totalIncome` and `total_Expense` are all the same, then:

```js
const obj = {"result":[{"customerId":"20572696","totalIncome":"260000","total_Expense":"130000","relationName":"VIJAYA","relationDOB":"23839","relation":"Daughter"},{"customerId":"20572696","totalIncome":"260000","total_Expense":"130000","relationName":"Riyaz","relationDOB":"26665","relation":"SPOUSE"},{"customerId":"20570000","totalIncome":"200000","total_Expense":"100000","relationName":"John","relationDOB":"26000","relation":"SON"}]};

let relations = {};
let identifierFields = {};

obj.result.forEach(({ customerId, totalIncome, total_Expense, ...rest }) => {
  relations[customerId] = (relations[customerId] || []);
  relations[customerId].push({ ...rest });
  
  if (!identifierFields[customerId]) identifierFields[customerId] = { customerId, totalIncome, total_Expense };
});

const result = Object.values(identifierFields).map((r, idx) => ({
  ...r,
  relations: relations[r.customerId]
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

This is more performant than simply spreading everything, as it only spreads the other properties in the object and `push`es everything else, saving you a lot of memory and time losses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object with key as customerId and value as aggregated for same id.

```js
const process = (data, track = {}) => {
  data.forEach(({ customerId, totalIncome, total_Expense, ...item }) => {
    if (!track[customerId]) {
      track[customerId] = {
        customerId,
        totalIncome,
        total_Expense,
        relations: [item],
      };
    } else {
      track[customerId].relations.push(item);
    }
  });
  return Object.values(track);
};

const data  =[{"customerId":"20572696","totalIncome":"260000","total_Expense":"130000","relationName":"VIJAYA","relationDOB":"23839","relation":"Daughter"},{"customerId":"20572696","totalIncome":"260000","total_Expense":"130000","relationName":"Riyaz","relationDOB":"26665","relation":"SPOUSE"},{"customerId":"20570000","totalIncome":"200000","total_Expense":"100000","relationName":"John","relationDOB":"26000","relation":"SON"}];


console.log(process(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```